# Authorization header not working for second request in same scenario

Tags: karate

**My Requirement -**

1. Create a issue using Post Request.
2. Read the issueId from the response and delete that Issue ID.

**Feature file which is NOT working:**

```
Feature: To Delete a issue after creating it
  Background:
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer '+ tokenId
  Scenario:
    Given url baseUrl+'/projects/5/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug'
    When method POST
    Then status 201
    * def issueToBeDeleted = response.iid
    Given url baseUrl+'/projects/5/issues/'+ issueToBeDeleted
    When method DELETE
    Then status 204
```

**Feature which is working:**

```
Feature: To Delete a issue after creating it
  Background:
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer '+ tokenId
  Scenario:
    Given url baseUrl+'/projects/5/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug'
    When method POST
    Then status 201
    * def issueToBeDeleted = response.iid
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer '+ tokenId
    Given url baseUrl+'/projects/5/issues/'+ issueToBeDeleted
    When method DELETE
    Then status 204
```

I had to call Authorization header again to make delete request. I assumed, if its defined in background then it should be called for all the requests. Am I making any mistake here?

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be doing:

```
* configure headers = { Authorization: "#('Bearer ' + tokenId)" }
```

Please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#http-header-manipulation